# how to fix syntax error on line 21 while accessing to properties of the Objects placed in a Array database, via For loops for comparison with If Else?

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops

by putting 0 instead of For loop in database[0].username its working fine but i want to check
for other username password values as well presents at[0] and[1] and so on positions
if there are more objects with proprieties inside of database array.
code: JavaScript file:

```
var database = [{
        username: "gurmel",
        password: "su"
    },
    {
        username: "nikita",
        password: "su"
    }
];

var newsFeed = [{
    username: "gurmel",
    timeline: "hi you'r doing good"
}];

var userNamePrompt = prompt("please enter your username below");
var passwordPrompt = prompt("please enter your password now");
var i;

function signin(user, pass) {
    if (user === database[
            for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
                i;
            }].username &&
        pass === database[0].password) {
        console.log(newsFeed);
    } else {
        console.log("this username or password does not exist");
    };
};

signin(userNamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

If statement's User value should be execute/compare for every objects presents in the database array.

Comment: Apparently, it is really difficult to navigate to line number #21 here. For clarity, it'd be helpful if you edit the title and body of this question.

Comment: At line #21, you're missing a closing parentheses. Change `if (user === database[` to if `(user === database)` . This should resolve the syntax error you're getting.

Comment: @AadityaSharma don't encourage the user to compare string with an array of objects. The comparison is wrong. And that's not the reason syntax error the OP is getting. The OP has closed the parentheses if you look closely.

Comment: @weegee I just checked for the syntax error at line #21, as he asked in the question. Didn't go through the entire code for checking any logical errors (as that's not the aim here).

Comment: @AadityaSharma that's why you are wrong. If not the issue which you said. He closed the parentheses no issue in that. This is a syntax error which you didn't figure out because you didn't read the whole code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This

```
database[for (i = 0; i <= 1; i++) {
  i;
}]
```

Does not does what you think, it does not return every value for the database array, because for loop doesn't return anything instead, you can filter a new array and check for every username and password using [`.filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) and if a value exists then it is a good username and password. Everything is explained in comments.

```js
var database = [{
    username: "gurmel",
    password: "su"
  },
  {
    username: "nikita",
    password: "su"
  }
];

var newsFeed = [{
  username: "gurmel",
  timeline: "hi you'r doing good"
}];

var userNamePrompt = prompt("please enter your username below");
var passwordPrompt = prompt("please enter your password now");
var i;

function signin(user, pass) {
  let chances = database.filter(obj => obj.username == user && obj.password == pass) // check for every username == user and password == pass and it is true then it will return a value array

  if (chances.length > 0) { // check if the value exist
    console.log(newsFeed);
  } else { // if it does not exist then display your error
    console.log("this username or password does not exist");
  };

}

signin(userNamePrompt, passwordPrompt);
```

Comment: Hi can you elaborate little more about the filter() function used as in what is happening here.

Comment: @Gurmelsingh Filter function checks every object you have in there with the condition you have given. If the condition matches then those objects are returned. Like if password matches and the username too then that object is returned. I checked that if anything is at least returned because if anything is really returned means the user has entered the right password